# Proxpy- certificate issue

Tags: certificates, openssl, proxy

I am using proxpy, a proxy server written in Python. It comes with its certificates and after installing one of the certificates in Firefox, I got 'Connection is untrusted'. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you paste the screen shot ?

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. Proxpy presents certificates with CN = proxpy. We need to dynamically generate certificates such that CN = host where host is the host of the request.